# HTML hiding <div> based on value

Tags: html

I'm very new to html and trying to hide some options in a web form based on if the user selects an option. For example if they select a food package, it should hide the custom food options. Is this something that can be done within html or requires script?

```html
<div class="large-2 columns">
  <label><b>Packages</b></label>
</div>
<!--column-->
<div class="large-10 columns">
  <div class="large-3 columns">
    <input type="radio" value="A" name="Package" checked><label>Standard Package</label>
  </div>
  <!--column-->
  <div class="large-3 columns">
    <input type="radio" value="B" name="Package"><label>Luxe Package</label>
  </div>
  <!--column-->
  <div class="large-3 columns">
    <input type="radio" value="C" name="Package"><label>Ultimate Package</label>
  </div>
  <!--column-->
  <div class="large-3 columns">
    <input type="radio" value="D" name="Package"><label>Custom Package</label>
  </div>
  <!--column-->
</div>
```

this is the code that I am using for the options, areas I want to hide are also div.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It cannot be done in HTML alone. The best way to do this would be with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need to have a java script for the same. Hope this works.

```js
function onChange() {
  const nodes = document.getElementsByName('Package');
  var selectedValue;
  // Get selected radio
  for (var i = 0, length = nodes.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].checked) {
      selectedValue = nodes[i].value;
      break;
    }
  }
  // Showing all nodes first
  const nodePostFix = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
  nodePostFix.forEach(node => {
    document.getElementById('hidden-for-' + node).style.display = 'block';
  });

  //Hide the selected node
  document.getElementById('hidden-for-' + selectedValue).style.display = 'none';
};
```

```html
<div class="large-2 columns">
    <label><b>Packages</b></label>
  </div>
  <div class="large-10 columns">
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <input type="radio" value="A" name="Package" checked  onchange="onChange()"><label>A</label>
        <div id="hidden-for-A">Hide on selecting A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <input type="radio" value="B"  name="Package" onchange="onChange()"><label>B</label>
        <div id="hidden-for-B">Hide on selecting B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <input type="radio" value="C" name="Package" onchange="onChange()"><label>C</label>
        <div id="hidden-for-C">Hide on selecting C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <input type="radio" value="D" name="Package" onchange="onChange()"><label>D</label>
        <div id="hidden-for-D">Hide on selecting b</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe i've got the script part working, not too sure on how to actually set the div I want to hide though? Maybe im missing something here

Comment: @joshwork There should be some connection between the hiding div and the selected option right? I opted the div id to be hidden depending on the selected option. You may need to create a logic which fits your scenario.

Comment: Currently its a bunch of seperate div's as its just a bunch of options for users to fill in information. I don't believe there is a connection. I've just been handed a html file and not too sure

Comment: Then you have to go like if value == a then hide div-one else if value === b then hide div-two like that.

Comment: Just sat down to carry on with this, not too sure what you mean about the referencing other div though. So i've got the demo bit with the labels that disappear, I have tried putting changing the <div> of another object to <div id="hidden-for-A"> and that hasnt worked, obviously im doing something wrong, maybe the scope is wrong for it so how would i go about making the options affect other parts of the form?

Comment: got it now thank you! didnt know id had to be unique, lesson learnt

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done using only HTML. It would be best to simply do this using a small script:

```js
const luxuryElement = document.querySelector("#luxury-div");
const customElement = document.querySelector("#custom-div");

function selected(value) {
  showElement(luxuryElement);
  showElement(customElement);
  
  if (value == 'luxury') hideElement(luxuryElement);
  if (value == 'custom') hideElement(customElement);
}

function hideElement(element) {
  element.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function showElement(element) {
  element.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```html
<div class="large-2 columns">
  <label><b>Packages</b></label>
</div>
<!--column-->
<div class="large-10 columns">
  <div class="large-3 columns">
    <input type="radio" onchange="selected('standard')" value="A" name="Package" checked><label>Standard Package</label>
  </div>
  <!--column-->
  <div class="large-3 columns">
    <input type="radio" onchange="selected('luxury')" value="B" name="Package"><label>Luxe Package</label>
  </div>
  <!--column-->
  <div class="large-3 columns">
    <input type="radio" onchange="selected('package')" value="C" name="Package"><label>Ultimate Package</label>
  </div>
  <!--column-->
  <div class="large-3 columns">
    <input type="radio" onchange="selected('custom')" value="D" name="Package"><label>Custom Package</label>
  </div>
  <!--column-->
</div>

<div id="luxury-div">To hide if luxury is chosen</div>
<div id="custom-div">To hide if custom is chosen</div>
```

Do note that this is just an example, there are many ways to go about this. The above script is just an example.

Comment: Ok, so from what I understand, luxuryElement is what i want to show when either of the first 3 are picked and anything i want to hide i set as customElement?

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label{
    display:none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked{
   display:none;
}
```